# Filter review queue by default

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-experience

The review queue continues to alienate and surprise those who try to use it.  This is not a good thing.

- Recurring complaints about failed audits
- Recurring complaints about rejected reviews and the fallout from them

My informal analysis after some 1000+ reviews is that the default review tools are too much like the firehose.  The experience could be streamlined a lot by adding filtering to the review queue, just like Stack Overflow already learns from the questions you vote on and acquire reputation in.

My quick and informal first cut at a suggestion is: *Default to a filtered view of the review queue* with the filter set up to questions where the reviewer has a positive reputation.

This could be tweaked in various directions.  If the reviewer has good karma in an unpopular tag, that should probably be a priority.  If the reviewer has massive reputation (gold badge?) for a particular tag, that should probably be a second priority.  There are probably more knobs you could add.

The filter should probably just use the existing filtering tools, so that the user can go in and change or remove the filter if they so please.  At least initially, it might be helpful if there was a callout which told you about this the first time you visit the review queue.

I am posting this as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) although I have not yet worked out all the details.  I am hoping this could at least stimulate the site's developers to implement something simple for a start, and we can take it from there.

Comment: Do I need to add examples to the bullet points, or are they clear enough as they are?  </innocent>

Comment: Obligatory [UHF clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXc5ltzKq3Y)