# Show posts to review only from chosen tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues, first-post-review

While reviewing first posts I noticed that I am shown new posts with all the tags. A few minutes ago I got [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50286138/1) for review, it's a question regarding the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) programming language, of which I have no knowledge. But as it looks, I can feel that the question is not properly formatted (it looks like there are some code lines not formatted as code).

But I can not edit that without knowing properly, so I skipped. This happens often. Some posts popup with tags which I don't have much knowledge of, so I skip.

What if we could choose some specific tags of which we have knowledge to understand the problems and mistakes to edit, or comment on, or even to decide *No action needed*?

Stack Overflow already has lists of the user's favourite and ignored tags, so I think it's much better if the review queue is filtered using those.

Comment: There is no shame in using skip ...

Comment: @rene Yeah. except for just a waste of time.

Comment: I think same goes with Late answers and Triage

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309583/filter-review-queue-by-default

Comment: Uhhm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrW6c.png not sure what you ask ..

Comment: current filter can only take a maximum of 3 tags. I'm suggesting to filter by all tags in favourite tag list and ignored tag list (by default).

Comment: I see. I doubt that will be implemented in 6 to 8 weeks as those queue queries are pretty heavy already, so I'm told. They barely manage to handle 3 tags, if they have to handle loads of them it will come to a crawl if not timeout.

Comment: A workaround for this is to set bookmarks with the filter set for groups of 3 of your favorite tags. Then you just click on the bookmarks. Alternately, you could use bookmarklets that set the filtered tags. Using bookmarklets would mean you only need one set of bookmarklets rather than a set of bookmarks for each review type.